# SnowFlake: Access rights in SQL vs. procedures

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sequence, sql-grant

I have the following initial situation in SnowFlake:
I want to retrieve the NextVal of a sequence in a procedure and get the following error message when calling the procedure:

> Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 3 at position 29
> : SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7 invalid identifier
> 'COMMON.SEQ_LAUF_ID'.

A select with the same user/role works fine:

Example SQL:

```
 SELECT COMMON.SEQ_LAUF_ID as nv FROM DUAL ;
```

Example Proc:

```
create or replace procedure MDP_Codes ( )
returns varchar
language sql
EXECUTE AS CALLER
as
$$
DECLARE
    rs   resultset default ( SELECT COMMON.SEQ_LAUF_ID as nv FROM DUAL ) ;
    hCur cursor for rs ;
    SQL_lauf_id varchar ;
BEGIN
    for hRow in hCur do
      SQL_lauf_id := hRow.nv ;
    end for;
    
    return SQL_lauf_id ;
END;
$$
;

call APPSMITH.MDP_Codes();
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot: SnowFlake
I have corrected this.

Comment: No problem, we are all here to learn.

Comment: Ich habe auch nocht ein 'EXECUTE AS CALLER' in die Procrdure eingefügt um die rechte des aufrufers zu nutzen. Das Ergebnis ist das Gleiche:

Comment: Please, comment in English.

Answer (score 1):

The code `SELECT COMMON.SEQ_LAUF_ID as nv FROM DUAL ;` is incorrect as it lacks `NEXTVAL`

```
SELECT COMMON.SEQ_LAUF_ID as nv FROM DUAL ; 
-- Invalid reference to sequence object without nextval: COMMON.SEQ_LAUF_ID.

-- should be
SELECT COMMON.SEQ_LAUF_ID.NEXTVAL as nv FROM DUAL ;
```

To grab the next value from sequence there is no need to use `RESULTSET` and cursor loop, simple assignment will suffice.

Full demo:

```
CREATE SCHEMA COMMON;
CREATE SEQUENCE COMMON.SEQ_LAUF_ID;

SELECT COMMON.SEQ_LAUF_ID.NEXTVAL;
 -- 1
 
 create or replace procedure MDP_Codes ( )
returns varchar
language sql
EXECUTE AS CALLER
as
$$
DECLARE
    SQL_lauf_id VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    SQL_lauf_id := (SELECT COMMON.SEQ_LAUF_ID.NEXTVAL);
    return SQL_lauf_id ;
END;
$$
;

CALL MDP_Codes();
-- MDP_CODES
-- 2
```

Comment: very beautiful. Thank you